# How to prevent substitution with two instances of C++ in an asciidoctor sentence?

Tags: asciidoctor

If C++ appears just once in a sentence, asciidoctor parses the string just fine.

If C++ appears twice, asciidoctor matches across `bar` in the example below.

Various attempts at [preventing substitutions](http://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#preventing-substitutions) do not work.

How can one typeset C++ two or more times in a sentence using asciidoctor?

```
. foo C++
. foo C++ bar C++ blah
. foo C\++ bar C++ blah
. foo C+\+ bar C++ blah
. foo C\+\+ bar C++ blah
. foo C+\+ bar C\++ blah
. foo C+\+ bar C+\+ blah
. foo C\\++ bar C\\++ blah
. foo C\\++ bar C++ blah
```

[image: cpp]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [built-in attributes](http://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#char-ref-table) are needed.

The following four samples are correctly parsed.

```
. {cpp}
. {cpp} and {cpp}
. `{cpp}`
. `{cpp}` and `{cpp}`
```

producing

[image: cpp]

Though there [may be](http://discuss.asciidoctor.org/Render-to-word-C-as-monospaced-td2141.html) a bug lurking somewhere.

If you want to [write](http://discuss.asciidoctor.org/Whats-wrong-with-this-simple-example-td2343.html) `c++` (in small letters), precede the lines above with `:cpp: c++`.